# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined with react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I try a lot more, I cant solve this please help me guys I have my backend working but this is my problem, I am using redux, my map is working on useState mode but I need to use redux to upgrade my code and my knowledge but this is my problem

[image]

this is my HomeScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Product from '../components/Product';
import { listProducts } from '../actions/productActions';

const HomeScreen = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const productList =useSelector(state => state.productList );
    const { loading, error, products } = productList;

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(listProducts())
    }, [dispatch]); 

    return (
        <>    
            <h1>Latest Products</h1>
            { loading ? (
                <h2>Loading...</h2>
            ) : error ? (
                <h3>{error}</h3>
            ) : (
            <Row>
                {products.map((product) => (
                    <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                        <Product product={product} />
                    </Col>
                ))}
            </Row>
            )}
        </>
    )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

this is my productReducers.js

```
import { 
    PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL
} from '../constants/productConstants';

export const productListReducer = (state = { products: [] }, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true, products: [] }
        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return { loading: false, product: action.payload }
        case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

this is my productAction.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { 
    PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL
} from '../constants/productConstants';

export const listProducts = () =>  async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST })

        const { data } = await axios.get('/api/products')

        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.message 
                ? error.response.data.message 
                : error.message,
        })
    }
}
```

this is my productConstants.js

```
export const PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST = 'PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST';
export const PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS = 'PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS';
export const PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL = 'PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL';
```

this is my store.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { productListReducer } from './reducers/productReducers';

const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList: productListReducer,
});

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, 
composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)));


export default store;
```

Comment: Get the console products...It must be an array

Comment: Can you check the `console.log of products`? What it's coming ?

Comment: @tedd yes, they have a list of products now. it's working

Comment: @JhonzTalaro, Great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in the reducer. it should be `products`, not `product`

```
export const productListReducer = (state = { products: [] }, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true, products: [] }
        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return { loading: false, products: action.payload }   // <<< Here <<<<
        case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Try printing the logs everywhere so that you can debug it easily.

1. print data inside your action. check if the intended data you are getting or not.
2. if yes, go to reducer. Print the `action.paylod` and updated store's content before returning.
3. Now if both the cases are true, you have the data. Go to component and print the `productList`. Check if you have the data you need.

Comment: Welcome... i can feel it. :)